# Using an integral to show that a family of vectors is linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, trigonometric-integrals

Consider the family of functions $L=(t\to \cos(nt))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.
It is demanded to calculate the integral $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \cos(nt)  \cos(mt) dt$, then deduce that L is a family of linearly independent vectors.
I know how to show that by using induction, however I don't really see how I could apply the result of that integral (which turns out to be $0$ by using the fact that the function is $2\pi$-periodic.
I would appreciate some help and hints.

Comment: If $n=m$ the integral cannot be zero.

Answer (score 1):

Let  $l_i $ be the family of functions and suppose that  $$\sum_i a_i l_i=0.$$  Then
$$\int \sum_i a_i l_il_j=0.$$
Since  $\int l_il_j$ is $0$ for $i\neq j $ and $1$ for  $i=j $, you get  $a_j=0$.